# Bind to XAML in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I have a resource loader that creates XAML on the fly (in this case a `StackPanel` is returned) how can I bind to this in the xaml?

My property is:

```
public StackPanel InfoPane {get;set;}
```

I have tried this but it doesnt work

```
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding InfoPane}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry, too long for a comment.)

You approach is correct, the following minimal example works for me:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding InfoPane}" />
</Grid>
```

Codebehind:

```
public StackPanel InfoPane { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InfoPane = new StackPanel();
    InfoPane.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "dynamically created" });
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

So, your problem must lie somewhere else. Maybe you set your `InfoPane` *after* setting the `DataContext` property of your window? Note that you do not invoke `PropertyChanged`, so the UI has no way of knowing that `InfoPane` has changed.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, after you said that I realised I hadnt called `NotifyPropertyChanges` !

Answer (score 1):

You do not need binding, all you need to do is add the StackPanel to the Children collection when the StackPanel has been created.

That said, my advise is to take a different route:

Put a content control in the Grid and bind its Content to actual content (not a control) and register for each type of content a ContentTemplate so the ContentControl will select the correct template depending on the content being displayed.

Creating UI in code should be avoided as much as possible because it is hard to maintain and WPF has ways to handle content dependent UI.

Comment: We are creating a help section with content that has to be displayed, in a rich format, on both Silverlight and WPF. Given silverlight doesnt support XPS or RTF we are rolling our own solution.  The "loader" generates XAML which we then display

Comment: Could you explain why that is only possible by code generated XAML ?

Comment: How else can we display it?

Comment: Erno explained how to display it.  If you can generate Xaml on the fly, you can generate a list on the fly.